# Java data field encapuslation newby questions

Tags: java, scope, encapsulation

Why does the data field value change? The text I'm reading doesn't explain it clearly. The chapter is mainly on data field encapsulation, little things to them that you do that might affect the code and things of that sort.

```
public class Questions {
    private static int j = 0;
    private static int i = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 2;
        int k = 3;
        {   
            j = 3;
            System.out.println("j is " + j);
        }
        k = i + j;
        System.out.println("k is " + k);
        System.out.println("j is " + j);
    }
}

/* output is: 
j is 3
k is 5
j is 3
*/ 
//but if you do this one thing:
public class Questions {
    private static int j = 0;
    private static int i = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 2;
        int k = 3;
        {   
            int j = 3;
            System.out.println("j is " + j);
        }
        k = i + j;
        System.out.println("k is " + k);
        System.out.println("j is " + j);
}
/* the output is: 
j is 3 
k is 2
j is 0
*/
```

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In the first code:

```
{   
    j = 3;
    System.out.println("j is " + j);
}
```

You are simple assigning a new value to the `static` field declared outside main. The change will persist even after the local block.

But in the second code:

```
{   
    int j = 3;
    System.out.println("j is " + j);
}
```

You are declaring a new block-scoped local variable, which hides the `static` field in that block. Any changed done to `j` in this block, is done in the block-scoped variable, and not to the static field. It goes out of scope outside that block. 
And the variable `j` which you use outside the block is nothing but the `static` field, which is not related whatsoever with the `j` declared inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new j (int j) inside the {}. That variable is different from the one you declared at the top of the class.

I am editing to add that that variable is used only inside the {}. Once you are out of there, the only "existing" j is the one declared at the top.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare int j in another scope (block-scope - within the curly brackets), You create a new *j* which dies when the curly brackets are over. Which means you'll be referencing the old *j* outside the brackets. Therefore J is 3 within the brackets and 0 outside.

```
int j = 0;

{   
   int j = 3;
   System.out.println("j is " + j); // j is 3
}

System.out.println("j is " + j);  //j is 0 out here
```

If you wanted to change the outer *j* inside the new scope, you could easily do this, by not using the keyword *int*.

```
int j = 0;

{   
   /*int*/ j = 3;
}

System.out.println("j is " + j); // j is 3
```

Block scopes easily creates confusion, creating new variables enhances the readablity of the code.